# AlarmManager executing task too often

Tags: android, task, alarmmanager, repeat

Target of the functionality is to execute a task which sets a value in all entries of the app-database to 0.
The task should be executed each day at midnight (or first time the phone get woken on the day (if I understood `AlarmManager.RTC` correctly)). 
The problem is that the task executes several times a day instead of only once.

In onCreate of the MainActivity:

```
// Calendar with timestamp midnight
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

// initiate Alarm to reset commits @ midnight
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

The class which contains the code that is executed:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        ContentValues APValues = new ContentValues();
        APValues.put(APEntry.AP_DAILY_COMMIT, 0);

        int rowsUpdated = context.getContentResolver().update(APEntry.CONTENT_URI, APValues, null, null);
        if (rowsUpdated == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Resetting commits failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Reset commits successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please, let us know whether provided answers solve your issue.

Comment: already added it. Will tell you tomorrow.

Comment: Seems to work so far. Going to keep an eye on it for the next couple of days.

Comment: Glad to know. If my answer was helpful, you can upvote it or accept as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your alarm is called multiple times. I can assume that probably you set the alarm multiple times. You can use `SharedPreferences` to check whether 1 day elapsed. So, your code could look like this:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (dayElapsed(context))
        {
            ContentValues APValues = new ContentValues();
            APValues.put(APEntry.AP_DAILY_COMMIT, 0);

            int rowsUpdated = context.getContentResolver().update(APEntry.CONTENT_URI, APValues, null, null);
            if (rowsUpdated == 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Resetting commits failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Reset commits successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean dayElapsed(Context context)
    {
        String lastUpdateTimeKey = "dayElapsed";
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        long lastUpdateTime = sharedPrefs.getLong(lastUpdateTimeKey, -1);
        long currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long oneDayMillis = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);
        long timeElapsed = currentMillis - lastUpdateTime;

        if (lastUpdateTime < 0 || timeElapsed >= oneDayMillis)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
            editor.putLong(lastUpdateTimeKey, currentMillis);
            editor.commit();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```